# Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this question, but since I missed the lecture I'm not where to start, and looking online doesn't help.

Can someone show me how to answer:

Given that X has a binomial distribution with n = 20 and p = 0.39, what is the probability that X takes on the value 8?

I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: You seem to have edited your question to change the problem. The answer given by Michael Hardy isn't really meaningful now. If you want to ask another question, I suggest you write another one. Also, revert the edit so others can understand Michael's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those instances where the quickest way to find the probability of an event is to find the probability that the event does **not** happen, and then subtract that from $1$.  Thus, find the probability that $X=0$, and subtract that probability from $1$.

It appears that you cannot well afford to skip lectures, since this is one of the most routine problems you'll ever see.

**Later note:** The question has been changed.  It now asks for $\Pr(X=8)$.  That's a standard formula.  My second paragraph remains intact.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Michael.

Comment: @Michael Question seems to have been edited, I suggested a roll back, but you might wanna track it to keep your answer in context

Answer (score 0):

This is if I got your question correctly:

You have 20 identical and independent (i.e. outcomes thereof do not affect each other) experiments, each is either success w.p. $P(S)=0.39$ or failure w.p. $P(F)=1-P(S)$. You do not care, which exactly (out of 20) experiments succeed or fail but you want the probability that exactly 8 thereof succeed.

For a better intuition think of 20 coin tosses w.p. $P(H)=0.39$ and all ways you can get 8 $H$ out of 20 tosses, $\binom{20}{8}$. The probability of this specific outcome is $0.39^8$ and therefore 12 $T \ 0.61^{12}$, hence:
$$
P(S)=\binom{20}{8} 0.39^8  0.61^{12}
$$

Comment: This doesn't match with Michael answers, as you see, the question has been edited to a completly different question. I think we should wait for OP to decide which question he wants to ask

Comment: I agree, but if the OP ants to learn something about Bernoulli experiments, this should be helpful too.