# Multiple rolls of a one hundreded sided dice

Tags: probability, random

Let's side I have a one hundred sided dice and a friend picks 8 random numbers from the dice.  I understand that if I roll the dice one time, he has an 8% chance of getting the roll correct.

My question is this: Let's say I roll the dice 4 times, what are the odds that he gets at least one correct guess?  I am assuming it is higher then 8% but don't know the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of NOT getting one of those $8$ numbers for four rolls would be 
$$x=\frac{92}{100}\cdot\frac{92}{100}\cdot\frac{92}{100}\cdot\frac{92}{100}$$

So the probability of hitting it at least once would be $(1-x)$

Comment: Thanks!  On a related question, how would you figure out the probability of winning at least two?

Comment: That's a little harder.  You need to figure out how many ways there are to pick the two out of the four rolls that are positive outcomes (combinations) and then the probability of each of those 2 getting a positive outcome (8/100) and the probability of the other 2 not hitting (92/100).  So ${4\choose2} (.08)^2(.92)^2$  That's the probability of getting exactly 2.  To that you would have to add in the probability of getting exactly 1 using the same method.  (Note the probability of getting at least 1 used a short cut).  Also see this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/211385/115823